# 504 Gateway timeout when using Azure Service Bus relay

Tags: service, azure, timeout, gateway, bus

I'm using Windows Azure Service Bus relay to expose a WCF service that lives on premises using  **basicHttpRelayBinding**.

For every request, the web service will just get some data out of a SQL Database using entity framework, then convert the results to an IEnumerable and finally send the response to the client.

Everything works just fine and I'm able to consume this web service from our web and worker roles hosted in the cloud, but every once in a while I'm getting the 504 Gateway timeout error while waiting for a response from the service, Typically this only happens with queries that take more than 30 - 40 seconds to execute.

Been doing some research and I've find out that this might be due to slow communication between a server acting as a gateway/proxy and some server upstream in the chain, but I'm not sure if there's any way to increase the timeout value so we don't get the 504 error.

Any help would be really appreciated.